# How can I reposition an entry form and button correctly on a background image?

Tags: wordpress, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a text widget that includes an entry form on top of a background image within a responsive theme that is using Twitter Bootstrap 2 for it's framework. I'm trying to positon the entry button and contact from correctly on the image. Right now it's in the middle, but I'm trying to move it down and to the left. Here is the code that I'm using for the widget. Can someone please help me figure out how what CSS to add inline to move the box and the button? (Then I can go in and tweak them, I just need to figure out what I need to add to do it.) Thanks!

```
<form style="-webkit-background-size: cover;-moz-background-size: cover;-o-background-size: cover;background-size: cover;padding: 3px;text-align: center;background: url(http://noahsdad.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/noahs-dad-side-bar.jpg) no-repeat center; padding: 25% 0;" action="http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify" method="post" target="popupwindow" onsubmit="window.open('http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=noahsdad', 'popupwindow', 'scrollbars=yes,width=550,height=520');return true" <input type="text" style="width:200px;height:20px;" name="email" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Enter your email address';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Enter your email address') {this.value = '';}" value="Enter your email address"/>
    </p>
    <input type="hidden" value="noahsdad" name="uri"/><input type="hidden" name="loc" value="en_US"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" />
</form>
```

I've changed a bit of the code since I first posted the question.

```
<form style="-webkit-background-size: cover;-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;background-size: cover;padding: 3px;text-align: center;background: url(http://noahsdad.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/noahs-dad-side-bar.jpg) no-repeat center;
padding: 30% 0;" action="http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify" method="post" target="popupwindow" onsubmit="window.open('http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=noahsdad', 'popupwindow', 'scrollbars=yes,width=550,height=520');return true">
    <p>
        <input type="text" style="width:170px;height:18px;margin-bottom:-110px;margin-left:-125px;" name="email" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Enter your email address';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Enter your email address') {this.value = '';}" value="Enter your email address"/>
    </p>
    <input type="hidden" value="noahsdad" name="uri"/><input type="hidden" name="loc" value="en_US"/>
    <input type="submit"  style="margin-bottom:-134px;margin-left:-220px;" value="Subscribe" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you meant to the bottom left corner. If so please use this:

```
<form style="-webkit-background-size: cover;-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;background-size: cover;padding: 3px;text-align:     center;background: url(http://noahsdad.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/noahs-dad-side-bar.jpg)      no-repeat center;
padding: 30% 0;" action="http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify" method="post" target="popupwindow" onsubmit="window.open('http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=noahsdad', 'popupwindow', 'scrollbars=yes,width=550,height=520');return true">
<p>
    <input type="text" style="width:170px;height:18px;float:left;margin-top:28%;" name="email" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Enter your email address';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Enter your email address') {this.value = '';}" value="Enter your email address"/>
</p>
<input type="hidden" value="noahsdad" name="uri"/><input type="hidden" name="loc" value="en_US"/>
<input type="submit"  style="float:left;margin-top:28%;" value="Subscribe" />
```

Comment: Phil, thanks. I've changed the code a little while I was testing it out. I've made a few changes to the code since posting the question. Do you mind looking at the new code and seeing how it looks, and if I  went about solving the problem the wrong way? Thanks.

Comment: Also the code that you posted doesn't seem like it would move the subscribe button, am I missing something?

Comment: Hi, I've edited the code again. Please deploy it and let me know if it's okay. It moves both the submit button and the enter email form into the bottom left corner.

Comment: Hi Rick, what do you mean? I've just updated the code in my answer. Could you please test it?

Comment: Yes it floats it to the left and uses a variable margin that will work with your responsive theme. If the form is too low, reduce the margin - and vice versa.

Comment: thanks for this, but i added that code to a new widget and I'm not sure if I'm not doing something wrong, but it looked way off. The image didn't show up correctly, the buttons were off the image, etc. Am I missing something? (Thanks for your help by the way.)

Comment: If the buttons are off then please reduce the % of the margin-top values. 'code'<input type="hidden" value="noahsdad" name="uri"/><input type="hidden" name="loc" value="en_US"/>
<input type="submit"  style="float:left;margin-top:28%;" value="Subscribe" />'code'